# how to add legend manually with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to add legend manually inside the picture. I tried to find an answer on the web but failed to find an appropriate one. Please advice.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
p = ggplot(gData, aes(seq, mue)) + geom_line(aes(x = seq, y = mue), lty=1, lwd=1) + xlim(-10, 10) + ylim(-1.0, 1.0)  + 

xlab(expression(paste(u[t-1],sep = ""))) + ylab(expression(paste(mu[t],""))) + 

geom_line(aes(x = seq, y = se1), type="b", lty=2, lwd=1.1) + geom_line(aes(x = seq, y = se2), type="b", lty=2, lwd=1.1) + 

theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 14), 

axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 14))
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand what exactly you are trying to do, but you can adjust the position of the legend with the `legend.position` parameter of the `theme()` function, e.g. `theme(legend.position="top")`. The function can also take coordinates as arguments. See here (http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/) for some examples of how you can change the legend in `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually choose a legend position using `theme(legend.position=c(num, num))`. Considering the OP's comment below, I took the following approach.

```
# Sample data
seq <- rep(c(1:10), times = 3)
value <- rep(c(10,9,6,5,3,2), each = 5)
category <- rep(c("se1", "me", NA), each = 10)
foo <- data.frame(seq, value, category, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = seq, y = value, color = category)) +
geom_line(lty=1, lwd=1) +
theme(legend.position=c(.8, .5)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have 3 lines, 1. se1, 2. mue, and 3, se2. Se1 and se2 basically the lower bound and upper bound and mu is the middle line. I want to have a legend only for mue and se1. How can I delete the se2 from the legend without deleting the 3 lines of the plot.

Comment: @SaikatSarkar I do not know how you formatted your data. What I did with my sample here was to name se2 NA in the data frame. You see the grey line, but se2 does not appear in the legend.

Comment: This is an excellent example. It helps me a lot to understand why and what is going on. color = category seems to be a nice way of doing this. But if I use "aes(x = seq, y = value, linetype = category" . Then I get Zig Zag lines. I dont know why. How to handle this problem.

Comment: I would like to get lines in black with lty rather than color.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with line type other than color

Comment: @SaikatSarkar I tried to assign colours manually, but that deletes se2 line. This is a bit tricky business. I need to step back and think again.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are really kind. Thank you for you help.  Thanking you again.